# scanf for numbers separated by space

Tags: c++, linux, scanf

I know the amount of numbers separated by space. The following code does work int Windows, but does not in Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    unsigned long k,p,q, all;


    cin >> k >> p >> q; 
    vector<long> klo(k);
    all = 0;
    for(unsigned long i = 0;i<k;i++){   
        scanf("%d", &klo[i]);
        all += klo[i];
    }
}
```

As I said, works perfectly under Windows, but Linux assign there some random values: `-1220155675-1220155675-12201556750`

What's wrong?

Comment: Why not simply use `std::cin >>` in the loop as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I compiled your code on Linux, it gave me the following error:

```
$: /tmp$ g++ -g foobar.c
foobar.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
foobar.c:17:28: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int*’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d", &klo[i]);
                            ^
```

I changed it to `scanf ( "%ld", &klo[i] );` and it worked.  Windows is tolerant.  I also had to add

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

as an additional include file.

Comment: `long` and `int` are the same size on Windows, which is why it works there despite technically invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the word bit size is different between platforms, you have long type in your vector and you are reading only `int` type, which could not rewrite the whole size of the long variable and you'll get a long variable with half its bytes uninitialized.

Try to change:

```
scanf("%d", &klo[i]);
```

Into:

```
scanf("%ld", &klo[i]);
```

`ld` denotes long decimal type.

Comment: Still nothing, but @Joachim Pileborg 's comment about cin fixned the problem. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` is for reading int. You are trying to read a long - that would be `%ld`.

One of the advantages of the C++ IO system is that `cin >> klo[i]` would do the right thing for both types.

Comment: `%ld` still does not work, but cin fixed the problem.